# pydiffmap: How to reverse Diffusion Map Embedding and reconstruct original variables from several principal components?

Tags: python, reverse, dimensionality-reduction

using pydiffmap, I could find a nice low dimension Manifold in my data, and extract what seems to be meaningful low dimension components.

I would like now to reverse the operator, and project my data back to my original high dimensional space keeping only these few important dimensions I could identify.

First, is this mathematically possible? And if so how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I just went into the Diffusion algorithm behind the package, and realized that there is no guarantee that you can go from a vector in the diffusion space back into the data space.

This is because the diffusion space represent the distances to the original data points. So if at least two points are different, the null vector in the diffusion space (at distance 0 of all original data points in the data space) will have no equivalent in the data space.

Hope this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

if you multiply the exponantiated markovian matrix with original
data you will have a denoised version of the original data, i dunno how to do it with pydiffmap

see this article:
https://www.cell.com/cell/pdf/S0092-8674(18)30724-4.pdf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).